# Django's user_passes_test always gets Anonymous User

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using the following class-based view and applying the [UserPassesTestMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.UserPassesTestMixin) to it to check some pre-conditions.

```
class SomeTestView(UserPassesTestMixin, APIView):

    def test_func(self):
        return check_precondition(self.request.user)

    def get(self, request):
        print("inside view")
        print("user: ", request.user)
        print("is_authenticated? ", request.user.is_authenticated)
        return Response({"status": "success"})
```

Below is my precondition:

```
def check_precondition(user):
    print("in user_passes_test")
    print("user: ", user)
    print("is_authenticated? ", user.is_authenticated)
    return True
```

Here's the output I am getting:

```
in user_passes_test
user: AnonymousUser
is_authenticated? False

inside view
user: John Doe/john@test.domain
is_authenticated? True
```

What I'm not able to understand is that why is the `request.user` anonymous inside the `user_passes_test` check. I want to run some precondition checks based on the user object.

Here is my sequence of middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I'm on Django `3.1.7` and djangorestframework `3.12.3`.

Answer (score 2):

> What I'm not able to understand is that why is the `request.user` anonymous inside the `user_passes_test` check.

The `UserPassesTestMixin` does *not* check if the user has logged in. Sometimes you might want to check a property that can be `True` for non-authenticated users. For example a view that should only be visible to non-superusers, or to a user that has not registered (yet), but is based on some session variables.

You can add an extra check with the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). But the way the Django REST framework handles this is normally with [**`permission_classes`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#overview-of-access-restriction-methods):

```
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class UserPassesSomeTest(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Some custom message'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        print("in user_passes_test")
        print("user: ", user)
        print("is_authenticated? ", user.is_authenticated)
        return True

class home(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, UserPassesSomeTest)
    
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks, but for my particular use case, I do not have access to the View definitions since they are coming from a package (social_django) which uses functional views. I was instead hoping to use `user_passes_test` decorator in my urls to wrap the view references and call a custom precondition to check whether or not the use is logged in. (I want to allow the URLs only for non-logged in users)

Comment: Also, as per docs, `user_passes_test` should have the complete `request.user` object as per the definition here, allowing for checking whether or not they are authenticated or anonymous. (ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test)

Comment: @Aldo: they pass the `request.user`, that's correct. But if the user is nog logged in, there is still a `request.user`: it is set to an `AnonymousUser` object. So you *can* check if the user is authenticated, but it is *not* done by the `user_passes_test` itself.

Comment: @Aldo: as for decorating views, you can use the `django-decorator-include` package to decorate an `include(..)` in the `urls.py`.

Comment: thanks, I am indeed using `django-decorator-include`, but the issue that still remains is that my decorator (user_passes_test) is unable to check the conditions I want to check because of the main issue highlighted in the question. Even authenticated users are coming as Anonymous users which is the primary issue.

Comment: @Aldo: just check this in the function, so return `return user.is_authenticated and ...` with `...` the extra thing you want to check. Beware however that a person that aims to login with a social account will thus first be unauthenticated, only after the callback of the social auth the user is logged in.

Comment: Understood your point, however in my use case, even requests from already logged in users are failing to get identified as authenticated. Not sure if I'm unable to convey properly. Happy to hop on to chat and discuss further.